# Fetching original element tag from jQuery post data instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to fetch orignal DOM element from jQuery post data like following:

```
.done(function (data) {
  if (data !== "UsernameError") {
    StopLoading();
    var dbtb = $('<table />').append(data).find('#datatable-responsive').html();

    // Convert the table into a javascript object                            
    var table = $(data).find('#datatable-responsive').get(0).tableToJSON(); 
    console.log(table);


    $('#datatable-responsive').dataTable({"bDestroy": true});
    var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('.bs-glyphicons').html();
    $('.bs-glyphicons').html(header);
    $('#tableProducts thead, #header').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#emptyText').hide();
  }
  else {
    StopLoading();
    ShowMessage("No eBay user was found under: " + $('.txtSearch').val());
  }
})
```

This is the problematic part:

```
   var table = $(data).find('#datatable-responsive').get(0).tableToJSON(); // Convert the table into a javascript object
  console.log(table);
```

I'm using jQuery extension table to json library to convert the html into the JSON and then fetch it into the datatable.. Since datatable only accepts JSON as data source I need to somehow convert it.

When I do like this:

```
$(data).find('#datatable-responsive').get(0)
```

This returns the original DOM element (The table it self), BUT, the table to json only accepts the actual selector as the first parameter like this:

```
$('#tableid').tableToJSON(); <<< correct way
```

And for me to fetch the actualy table I do:

```
$(data).find('#datatable-responsive').get(0).tableToJSON()

or 

$(data).find('#datatable-responsive')[0].tableToJSON()
```

These two methods above give me following error:

```
Error: tableToJSON is not a function
```

How can I fix this ?

@Rajaprahbu when using:

```
   console.log($(data).find('#datatable-responsive').eq(0));
```

I'm getting object instead of native DOM element... still :/

Edit2: This is the link for the plugin itself:

```
https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json
```

Comment: `$(data).find('#datatable-responsive').eq(0).tableToJSON()`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I'm getting Array [  ] <<< when using this.. This looks like the array is empty,, but it shouldnt be :/

Comment: jQuery objects "look like" arrays. It may be you have no matches. You should not use ID selectors in dynamic data anyway as dupes cause issues. Use a class instead (almost as fast). `$(data).find('#datatable-responsive').tableToJSON()` alone will operate on the first match, or do nothing if there is no match.

Comment: @GoneCoding I understand what your'e saying... But when I do $(data).find('#datatable-responsive') <<< that retuns me an object, which is not what tableToJSON() method requires.. It requires native DOM element to operate with, if not it'll return empty JSON array as it is right now

Comment: @JadinStojadin: According to the docs I found, `tableToJSON` is a jQuery plugin in which case it is not a "native DOM element", but a jQuery extension..Please provide a link to the tableToJSON you are using.

Comment: @GoneCoding I agree with you, but that's not what I ment...  What I ment is that the syntax for invoking the method is that it accepts an selector before invoking it like this: $('someid').tableToJSON(); In my case I'm trying to extract the native DOM element (table) from the post data and then use its selector id to convert it to JSON. My apologies if I haven't explained it correctly...

Comment: You are creating a disconnected DOM element, wrapped with jQuery with `$(data)`. Whether it actually needs to be in the DOM is another question. That I do not know.

Comment: @GoneCoding I've provided the link in my original question.. But I'm happy to use other methods to convert the post data table into JSON itself...

Comment: @GoneCoding Now I'm not sure either, but for some reason when I invoke the method with .get(0).tableToJSON() I get an error that tableToJSON is not an function for some reason

Comment: `.get(0)` returns the first DOM element in the jQuery collection. DOM elements do not have a `tableToJSON` function unless something adds it to the DOM element dynamically (possible, but unlikely). You need to use `.eq(0)` or `.first()` to deal with a jQuery wrapped version of the first DOM element..

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are all out by a small detail here and there.

`console.log($(data).find('#datatable-responsive').eq(0));` will indeed return a jQuery object and not a DOM element, but that is what you need.

`$(data).find('#datatable-responsive').get(0)` and $(data).find('#datatable-responsive')[0]` both return a DOM element but that is *not* what you needed.

It should be either simply:

```
var table = $(data).find('#datatable-responsive').tableToJSON();
```

which should cater for a non-match by returning a blank result, or return the JSON of the table.

Other options are:

```
var table = $(data).find('#datatable-responsive').eq(0).tableToJSON(); 
var table = $(data).find('#datatable-responsive').first().tableToJSON();
```

### A few notes:

- `.get(0)` returns the first DOM element in the jQuery collection. `[0]` does the same.
- `.eq(0)` returns the first DOM element in the jQuery collection, but wrapped in a jQuery object of its own.
- `$(data)` simply converts your loaded content into detached DOM elements.
- Do not use IDs for identifying elements in dynamically loaded content. Use classes to ensure duplicates are not present, ever.